# How to set min date in Tempus Dominus bootstrap 4 datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datetime, bootstrap-4

I'm having a hard time knowing the syntax as to how do i set the minDate to the current date as day passes by. Is there a way for me to set that way? Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            var $dp1 = $("#datetimepicker1");
          $dp1.datetimepicker({

        //i dont know the syntax

          });

        });
</script>
```

Also, I'm having hard time to insert the values to my db.. maybe it has something to do with this.

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target- 
input="nearest">
                <input type="text" name="eventDate" class="form-control 
datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
                  <div class="input-group-append" data- 
target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"> 
</i></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Expected output should be that the available dates are just the current date and the dates onward.

Comment: $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker('minDate', moment(new Date()).add(1,'days'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use minDate function as below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                minDate: new Date(),
                // minDate: '03/06/2019',
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY H:s A'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Hope it helps you :)